# Can i call function when button disabled and modify set enable at inspect element CSS style in FF or Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, extjs

I have a Save Button in my Extjs interface/javascript,and i already set disable to true to prevent some admin save thing,then i try inspect element on google chrome and modify it back to enable then it able to click it!!

This may be a stupid question
My question is:

Can the button save thing after modify on google chrome inspect element?

Did anyone got idea to prevent some html developer to  modify on inspect element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anyone can change the disabled property in the user agent to false using various methods (e.g. DOM inspector, local script). Do not depend on **anything** client-side in regard to security, clients can do anything. Always check and validate at the server, regardless of what you think might have been done on the client.